# Why is my state_publisher build complaining about tf::TransformBroadcaster?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am actually trying to put together enough to visualize my URDF model in RVIZ.
I currently have two files in my workspace:

- …_ws/src/rbot_description/urdf/rbot.urdf
- …_ws/src/rbot_description/src/state_publisher.cpp

When I call catkin_make the state_publisher fails to build.  The failure message reads:
"… undefined reference to 'tf::TransformBroadcaster::sendTransform(geometry_msgs::TransformStamped_std::allocator<void > const&)' "

What do I need to do to fix this error?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/105911/why-is-my-state_publisher-build-complaining-about-tf::transformbroadcaster?/) by [flb](https://answers.ros.org/users/8821/flb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2013-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

"undefined reference to" error occurs when object file (.so file), corresponding to a particular included header has not been linked to your target (the executable to be built). In this case, tf/transform_broadcaster.h.

try adding this line in your CMakelists.txt:

target_link_libraries("name of executable"    "location of file"/_tf.so   "location of file"/_tf2.so )

put the location of the file _tf.so and _tf2.so in the respective "location of file"

eg.
target_link_libraries(state_publisher    opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf/_tf.so  opt/ros/groovy/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tf2/_tf2.so )

Also, if not added, add tf package dependency in manifest.xml.

---

Originally posted by [CryptoKnight](https://answers.ros.org/users/19952/cryptoknight/) with karma: 16 on 2014-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0